# D3.JS ticks method not working on x-axis that is using dates

Tags: d3.js

I've been working on this problem for several days and have not been able to find a solution. I am trying to make a graph of new covid cases for each day, but  with over a year of data, I can't have a tick for each day. Unfortunately everything I've tried so far, does not limit the number of ticks on the x-axis, and the result is quite ugly.

[image]

As it currently stands, here is my code for my x-axis and ticks where I am trying to set the ticks to once every two months.

```
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
                .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(2))
```

However, I've also tried just adding a hard count to the number of ticks by doing something like this:

```
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
                .ticks(5)
```

Unfortunately, adding a headcount to the number of ticks has not work for me either.  I've also tried moving my code for limiting the number of ticks to where I call the x-axis group with something like this:

```
yAxisGroup.call(yAxis)
     .ticks(5)
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm not sure if its needed, but here is the code for the entire component. This entire project is in react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

export default class NewCasesGraph extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate = () => {
       
        let covidArray = Object.entries(this.props.data.cases);

        for(let i = covidArray.length - 1; i > 1; i--){
            let currentDay =parseInt(covidArray[i][1])
            let previousDay =parseInt((covidArray[(i-1)][1]) || 0)
            covidArray[i][1] = currentDay - previousDay
        }

        for(let j = 0; j <covidArray.length; j++){
            covidArray[j][0] = new Date(covidArray[j][0])
        }

        // console.log(covidArray)

        this.updateGraph(covidArray)
    }

    updateGraph(data){
        // console.log('data: ', data)
        
        // tweem
        const widthTween = (d) => {

            let i = d3.interpolate(0, x.bandwidth());

            return function (t){
                return i(t)
            }

        }

        // dimensions
        const dimensions = {
            height: 500,
            width: 1000
        }

        const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100}



        const svg = d3.select('.canvas')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', dimensions.width)
            .attr('height',dimensions.height)

        const graphWidth = dimensions.width -margin.left - margin.right
        const graphHeight = dimensions.height - margin.top - margin.bottom

        // create graph
        const graph = svg.append('g')
            .attr('width', graphWidth)
            .attr('height', graphHeight)
            .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

        const xAxisGroup = graph.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${graphHeight})`);

        // set x axis text
        xAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-40)')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
            .attr('fill','grey')

        const yAxisGroup = graph.append('g');

        // create y scale
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([ graphHeight, 0])

        // cretae a band scale
        const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, graphWidth])
            .paddingInner(0.2)
            .paddingOuter(0.2)

            // create the axae
            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
                .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(2))

            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
                .ticks(4)
                .tickFormat(d =>  `${d.toLocaleString()} cases`);


            const t = d3.transition().duration(750)

            // join data to rects
            const rects = graph.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)

            // remove exit selection
            rects.exit().remove();

            // update any scales (domains)
            y.domain([0,d3.max(data, d => d[1])]);
            x.domain(data.map(item => item[0]));

            // update current shapes in the dom
            rects.attr('width', x.bandwidth)
                .attr('fill', 'orange')
                .attr('x', (d) => x(d[0]))

         //handle enter selection
        // append the enter section to the DOM
        rects.enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('width', 0)
            .attr('height',0)
            .attr('y', graphHeight)
            .attr('fill', '#5FA19E')
            .attr('x', (d) => x(d[0]))
            .merge(rects)
            .transition(t)
            .attrTween('width', widthTween)
            .attr('y', (d) => {
                return y(d[1])
            })
            .attr('height', d => graphHeight - y(d[1]));

        // add mouseOver
        // graph.selectAll('rect')
        //     .on('mouseover',(event, d) =>{

        //     })

        // call axae
        xAxisGroup.call(xAxis);
        yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

        console.log(svg)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>New Cases Graph</h2>
                <div className="canvas">

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That's expected, since you're using a band scale. You can either change the scale (for a time scale) or eliminate some ticks, as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44224857/5768908) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199219/5768908).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for `ticks` method for [d3-axis](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks)

`This method has no effect if the scale does not implement scale.ticks, as with band and point scales. To set the tick values explicitly, use axis.tickValues. To set the tick format explicitly, use axis.tickFormat.`

So, if your domain contains every date over a year, use the below method to restrict the number of ticks.

```
xAxis.tickValues(x.domain().filter((e,i)=>i%60==0));
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199108/d3-v4-scaleband-ticks) the same questions answered before.